# Android resolution independent Bitmap from ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have a Bitmap which is 1200 pixels in both height and width. 
And I put it in ImageView. My app requires that later on I get the Bitmap from the ImageView so that I get the same quality of the Bitmap just when put in the ImageView. If I do it with getDrawingCache for the Layout I get bad image since I have to scale to the original size of the Bitmap and there is quality loss.

So is there any resolution independent way to get the image from the ImageView in its original size?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `getDrawable` function.

```
Drawable image=imageview.getDrawable ()
```

Comment: And if I convert it to Bitmap via BitmapDrawable will it return the Bitmap in its original size?